# Temporary Data Retention

Tags: database, database-design

I have a Database containes information about all the branches of our company around the country. Now I want to put some new data to this database, but these data would become irrelevant in a short time (like 4 weeks). These temporary data will be needed few times a year, but each time the format and nature of data is different.

How should I handle situation like this? Should I keep creating new tables everytime I need to store the temporary data and delete the tables after the data become irrelevent or there is some common patterns to handle situation like this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they are not temporary in the sense of created within a session and not needed afterwards, using regular tables and removing them once the need for them is gone looks like a good way to handle the situation.